# not able to create lagom scala project behind proxy

Tags: proxy, lagom

I am trying to create a new lagom scala project on windows 7 machine (behind proxy) but I get error message "org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git://github.com/lagom/lagom-scala.g8.git: Connection time out"

Here is the command : sbt new lagom/lagom-scala.g8

I have the proxy environment variable http_proxy set but still I get this error. Any thoughts idea..to make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a discussion about this at https://github.com/lagom/lagom/issues/683

The conclusion is that this is a limitation of sbt 0.13.13, which uses the git protocol to clone templates and cannot be made to use an alternate protocol.

You can work around this by both forcing a newer version of sbt and specifying the complete https URL of the repository, like this:

```
sbt new -Dsbt.version=0.13.15 https://github.com/lagom/lagom-scala.g8
```

Comment: tried the above command but I get this error: Template not found for: -Dsbt.version 0.13.15 https://github.com/lagom/lagom-sca
la.g8

Comment: The latest sbt launch script is more strict about argument ordering. Try `sbt -Dsbt.version=0.13.15 new https://github.com/lagom/lagom-scala.g8`. I also recommend subscribing to [issue #683](https://github.com/lagom/lagom/issues/683) for updates, as this has already been discussed there.